# Make sizing adjustable

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I really like how well the SE app works, but I would like to be able to change the size of text on the screen to be smaller. Especially when looking at question lists, the text is too large for me to read easily. Instead, I have to focus my eyes on individual parts of the word as I go or hold the phone away from my face. Here is a screenshot of the Message active questions list:

[image: screenshot]

I understand that the view is designed to be readable for anyone who has impaired vision, but could we have a zoom/text size feature in settings?